# How do I diagnose and fix an unknown crash on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, crash

Crash only occurs when playing videogames, and only some of them.  Entire PC crashes/locks up, not just the game.

Phasmophobia, black screen with no warning and I have to restart PC to fix.

Dead by Daylight, monitor loses connection with no warning and the game crashes.  Other applications seem to remain in-tact (I can still talk to people over Discord if I was in a call prior).  This crash in particular has gotten significantly more frequent with playtime, when I got the game I could play mostly unhindered but I can barely get a match in anymore before it dies.

I'm not really sure what to look for in event viewer, I thought it might be a dcom issue but fixes I've tried haven't worked and most complaints suggest this doesn't cause a black screen.  DBD crashes in particular I'll check event viewer and find nothing of interest.

Comment: Start with the Reliability History app.  Control Panel, Security and Maintenance.  It is easier than Event Viewer to get an initial look at the issue.

Comment: Phasmophobia stopped working, desktop window manager stopped working several times, and there were two hardware errors listed on Nov 28th within the same minute which I believe was one of these crashes.

Comment: Source
Windows

Summary
Hardware error

Date
‎11/‎28/‎2020 10:53 PM

Status
Not reported

Description
A problem with your hardware caused Windows to stop working correctly.

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: LiveKernelEvent
Code: 187
Parameter 1: 1
Parameter 2: 0
Parameter 3: 0
Parameter 4: 0
OS version: 10_0_18363
Service Pack: 0_0
Product: 768_1
OS Version: 10.0.18363.2.0.0.768.101
Locale ID: 1033

Comment: For the hardware errors for starters, update BIOS, and the all drivers using the Manufacturer’s driver update App.  For the software errors, open cmd.exe with run as Administrator and run DISM.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth and the SFC /SCANNOW  .  Restart and test again

Comment: Crashed again, this time without any info in the Reliability Monitor.  Just notes that I forced it to shut off.  Waited a minute as well just to make sure anything noteworthy would appear.

Comment: If it was just a software crash, I would (here and at the beginning) suggest a Windows 10 Repair Install. But that will not fix hardware issues and you do need to do Manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostics first.

Comment: hi, see if it's helpful to you: https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/computer-crashes-when-playing-games.html

Comment: Coming back in after a long while.  Installed a Windows update which appeared to fix the DBD crash.  Phas continued to crash w/out a notification, DBD has only recently started to crash regularly again w/ the hardware error.  HP's only other fix options are to reinstall windows, which I'd prefer not to do if possible.